# Have relative URL paths still use HTTPS

Tags: url, ssl, https, protocols, relative-path

I use relative paths all over my site, for example "/my/desired/path" which becomes `http://somesite.com/my/desired/path`.

Only problem is now I've switched from http to https, and my relative paths still seem to use HTTP.

How can I get all relative paths to use https instead?

Comment: Try // to be relative from root and request agnostic, though it should work with a single as well...

Comment: //my/desired/path I don't believe is valid.

Comment: What's your evidence? Relative paths should reuse the current protocol, host, and port.

Comment: No evidence,  and never tried it before because I use a single / with no issues.  My thought process was including scripts from a CDN you can use // to pull either http or https depending on which protocol the page is using.  Sorry if it was a waste :)

Comment: @ejp...oops, forgot to tag you.

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network. Perhaps superuser.com or serverfault.com since its a configuration issue.

Comment: @MatthewJohnson I wasn't asking you for evidence. I was asking the OP why he thought this wasn't working. I *didn't* forget to tag you.